# Make a 100% width div in a 300px container

Tags: class, html, width

I want to make a 100% width div in a 300px container, how is it posible? tryed postiton relative and absoulte with no success.

```
.container { margin:0 auto; text-align:center; background-color:black; width: 300px;}
.normalOne { background-color:grey; height: 50px;}
.hundredProcent { background-color:blue; height: 50px; width:100%;}
.normalTwo { background-color:red; height: 50px;}

<div class="container">
  <div class="normalOne"></div> 
  <div class="hundredProcent"></div> 
  <div class="normalTwo"></div> 
</div>
```

And here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/2U893/

Comment: You mean, 100% of the width of the window?

Comment: no 100% browserwindow, so the class .hundredProcent goes out side the 300px container 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added one addition div inside `div.hundredProcent` with following style:

```
style='position:absolute; background-color:yellow; height: 50px; width:100%;left:0px;'
```

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2U893/3/). You should not set `position:relative` to `.container` or
`.hundredProcent` div's

Comment: This solution has a limitation that the parent element should not have relative position

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by CSS alone. Use Javascript; something like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hundredProcent')[0].style.width = 
    document.body.clientWidth+'px';
```

for instance in the `onload` handler.

Make sure it works on all browsers that you need it to work on. I'm not even sure if `getElementsByClassName` is implemented in all modern browsers, so you may need to give the div an `id` to positively identify it.

Comment: ok, no this doesnt work in ie8/ie7, and it only make one side 100% :( http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/dtGcS/

Comment: Yes, then you'll need to give the div an ID and use `getElementById` in order to make it work in all browsers. And the div is still sitting in the container div, so the left edge is the same as the left edge of the container. You'll have to adjust that too.

Comment: Or, move the div out of the container and all your troubles are over.